# In Bayesian, what is the effect of prior on the curvature of posterior?

Tags: bayesian, prior, uncertainty

Just wonder about the simplest example, I have a simple Normal prior on my scalar parameter $w$.

$$P(w|D) \sim P(D|w) P(w)$$

$$P(w) = \mathcal{N}(0,\alpha^2)$$

When I increase $\alpha$ from 0 to $\infty$, how would the curvature of $P(w|D)$ changes?

Comment: When you ask about the "curvature", are you interested specifically in the [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_a_graph) in the strict sense (related to the second derivative of the function), or do you mean something else?

Comment: Yes! The second order derivative, in the 1D case is fine!

Comment: In general wouldn't this depend on $ P(D \mid w) $?

Comment: @KevinLi, yes. But I want to know, when P(D|w) is fixed, how does regularization prior affect the curvature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your clarification in the comments, it appears that you are interested in the second derivative of the posterior, not the [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_a_graph) in its strict sense.  Obtaining this is just a matter of basic calculus.

---

To facilitate our analysis, let's use the alternative notation $\pi_D(w) \propto L_D(w) \pi_0 (w)$ so that we are not using generic function notation.  From your specification we have $\pi_0 (w) = \text{N}(w|0,\alpha^2)$.  With a bit of simple calculus on the [normal density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), the derivative of the specified prior density is:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\frac{d \pi_0}{dw}(w) = \frac{d \text{N}}{dw}(w|0,\alpha^2) &= - \frac{w}{\alpha^2}\cdot \text{N}(w|0,\alpha^2) = - \frac{w}{\alpha^2}\cdot \pi_0(w).
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Then, using repeated application of the product rule you get:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\frac{d \pi_D}{dw}(w) 
&= \frac{d L_D}{dw}(w) \cdot \pi_0(w)  + L_D(w) \cdot \frac{d \pi_0}{dw}(w) \\[6pt]
&= \Bigg[ \frac{d L_D}{dw}(w) - \frac{w}{\alpha^2} \cdot L_D(w) \Bigg] \pi_0(w), \\[10pt]
\frac{d^2 \pi_D}{dw^2}(w) 
&= \Bigg[ \frac{d^2 L_D}{dw^2}(w) - \frac{1}{\alpha^2} \cdot L_D(w) - \frac{w}{\alpha^2} \cdot \frac{dL_D}{dw}(w) \Bigg] \pi_0(w) + \Bigg[ \frac{d L_D}{dw}(w) - \frac{w}{\alpha^2} \cdot L_D(w) \Bigg] \frac{d\pi_0}{dw}(w) \\[6pt] 
&= \frac{1}{\alpha^2} \Bigg[ \alpha^2 \cdot \frac{d^2 L_D}{dw^2}(w) + \Big( \frac{w^2}{\alpha^2}-1 \Big) L_D(w) - 2w \cdot \frac{dL_D}{dw}(w) \Bigg] \pi_0(w). \\[6pt] 
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Taking the limit as $\alpha \rightarrow \infty$ you get:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty} \frac{d \pi_D}{dw}(w) &= \frac{d L_D}{dw}(w) \cdot \pi_0(w), \\[8pt]
\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty} \frac{d^2 \pi_D}{dw^2}(w) &= \frac{d^2 L_D}{dw^2}(w) \cdot \pi_0(w).
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$